# PHP define a function output as variable

Tags: php, function, variables, output

Say I have a function that brings a title across, for example:

`get_title();` which outputs "title".

I want to set this as a variable such as `$title = get_title();`

Unfortunately this just echo's out the function and doesn't catch it for the variable. How should I be doing this?

I want to use the variable for an if statement.

`if ($title == "no title") { stop }`

Comment: If you are having this kind of issues, [Here is a very good place to get started with php](http://devzone.zend.com/6/php-101-php-for-the-absolute-beginner/)

Comment: What is `stop` by the way?

Comment: Pseudo-code @putvande I do believe the OP must've meant `exit;` or something similar to stop a process.

Comment: Thank you Ibu, I'm pretty good with PHP but it's been a long day, just couldn't seem to do the right search to find my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have no access to modify the function `get_title`, you can always use [output buffers](https://www.php.net/ob_get_contents).

```
<?php
ob_start();
get_title()
$title = ob_get_contents();
```

The clear solution would be returning the value of title instead of echoing it.

```
<?php

function get_title() {
    $title = // black box //;
    return $title;
}

$title = get_title();
```

As you pointed out, if you don't want the function to output anything onto the screen, you can use ob_end_clean() to destroy any output that get_title() may have.

Comment: Thank you all, I couldn't change the original function so this is the only way to go. I'm going to do some homework on this ob_start(); business, never seen it before but it looks very interesting.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'd been fighting with something similar for WordPress for about 2 hours. The first bit of code in your answer solved it for me. One thing to note, I had to add `ob_end_clean();` after setting the variable. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 4):

You have to return your variable instead of echoing it.

```
function get_title() {
    return "title";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You just need to return the title.

```
function getTitle(){
    $title="title";
    //echo $title;
    return $title; //return instead of echoing
}
```